# Incorrect Cart Price Calculation on Multi-Currency

Tags: cart, tax, multicurrency

Assuming the following values:

```
Product Base Price: 80 including tax
Tax: 10%
Conversion Rate to other currency: 4.5889
```

I still couldn't figure out why the cart item final price equals `333.74`.

My computation:

Less the Tax from the Base Price:

```
(80 - 10%) = 72
```

Convert the Amount:

```
72 * 4.5889 = 330.4008
```

Final price should be `330.4008`, so where does `333.74` come from. I have checked the tax rules, no other tax rule defined, no promotions defined.